# Calling BFGS optimization in C++ from optim.c

Tags: c++, c, r, optimization, statistics

So I have to rewrite my R code to C++. That is relatively easy, given the `Rcpp` package. I came across a problem while solving an optimization problem. In R I call:

```
optimum_optim = optim(par=A, fn=negative_LL, gr=negative_grad_LL, .c = c, .t = t, .i = i, .N = N, method = 'BFGS')
```

Given that I have rewritten the `negative_LL` and `negative_grad_LL` functions into my C++ file already I wanted to call the underlying routine for BFGS optimization from R: it is the `vmmin` function from optim.c
I have the problem that I cannot understand the signature of that function. It is:

```
vmmin(int n0, double *b, double *Fmin, optimfn fminfn, optimgr fmingr,
      int maxit, int trace, int *mask,
      double abstol, double reltol, int nREPORT, void *ex,
      int *fncount, int *grcount, int *fail)
```

It's not that I did not put any effort into search - I just cannot find a description... Could someone please help call this function in my particular case (and tell me what the arguments are)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've already been using this advice, but you need to go a bit deeper: ["Use the source, Luke"](http://wiki.c2.com/?UseTheSourceLuke).

My starting point was to, from the R console, type simply

```
optim
```

This prints the R source code of that function. There I saw it calls

```
.External2(C_optim, par, fn1, gr1, method, con, lower, upper)
```

My favorite mirror for the R source code is [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/wch/r-source). If you head there, search for "optim", and filter only the C results, we'll go to the top hit, [`src/library/stats/src/optim.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/src/optim.c). Then we can see how the C-level [`optim()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/src/optim.c#L177) (line 177) function [calls `vmmin()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/src/optim.c#L295) (line 295).

The way `optim()` initializes those arguments is as follows

```
int n           length(par)
double *b       vect(npar); dpar[i] = REAL(par)[i] / (OS->parscale[i])
double *Fmin    0.0
optimfn fn      function defined in the C code
optimgr gr      function defined in the C code
int maxit       asInteger(getListElement(options, "maxit"))
int trace       asInteger(getListElement(options, "trace"))
int *mask       mask = (int *) R_alloc(npar, sizeof(int));
                for (i = 0; i < npar; i++) mask[i] = 1;
double abstol   asInteger(getListElement(options, "abstol"))
double reltol   asInteger(getListElement(options, "reltol"))
int nREPORT     asInteger(getListElement(options, "REPORT"));
void *ex        OptStruct OS; /* tons of stuff done to this */
int *fncount    0
int *grcount    0
int *fail       0
```

I haven't put in all the details here, but I believe this should be enough to help you figure out how you need to use these things in your own function, once you find out about one other thing: the control list in `optim()`. If you notice in the `.External2()` call from above, there's an argument called `con`. This is defined in the R code as

```
con <- list(trace = 0, fnscale = 1, parscale = rep.int(1, npar),
        ndeps = rep.int(1e-3, npar),
        maxit = 100L, abstol = -Inf, reltol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps),
        alpha = 1.0, beta = 0.5, gamma = 2.0,
        REPORT = 10, warn.1d.NelderMead = TRUE,
        type = 1,
        lmm = 5, factr = 1e7, pgtol = 0,
        tmax = 10, temp = 10.0)
```

though these elements can be overridden by user input in the `control` argument, and if you check out `help("optim")`, you'll see

> The ‘control’ argument is a list that can supply any of the following components:
>       ‘trace’ ...

The C function refers to this list by the name `options` that you see referenced several times in the table I constructed above.